# Show path in Google Static maps

Tags: google-maps

I can show a path in Google Static Maps that is made of a collecion of points.
I can show a path in Google Static Maps that is made of enc of overview_polyline.
But, in most cases, I cannot show a path that has both:  points and enc.
Alsthough I see the path in regular Google-Maps.
Sometimes it does work as you can see in:
http://www.mobile-gap.com/where2go/launch.php?jump_to=9,13
But in most cases it shows only one or the other.
My app (trips and Events) enables the users to add a path that is a combination of both.

Answer (score 1):

So the example in the question as the benchmark of implementation has this long URL in image tag "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&markers=color:0xFFFF00|label:1|40.74896068875827,-73.98549273862306&markers=color:0xFFFF00|label:2|40.7488758,-73.9680091&markers=color:0xFFFF00|label:3|40.705866,-74.00424&markers=color:0xFFFF00|label:4|40.7105139,-74.0155469&markers=color:0xFFFF00|label:5|40.6892494,-74.0445004&path=color:0x0000ff|weight:3|enc:kwuwFvhqbMbQ{i@lFqPpGmSn@uBiCuA_Am@o@g@k@i@sA}@eByA}AyA{AuAu@y@{@s@oEmDuJsH{HqGoFcFkCwBaAq@sEwD_@c@{@gAkBoCk@k@y@i@aCyAcEgDeA{@*@WSMMGMIe@Us@]m@E]EMIw@`C{ByAwByAt@eC@QJ_@FIJCJBz@vAv@`A`A|@d@Z`@JRNbBdA\RPHtBvA^VPX^^pAhA|A`AlAv@t@n@xAnBrAjB~@~@hHfGlHbHjR~N&path=color:0x0000ff|weight:3|enc:ivuwFrxmbMxC|BlDhCv@t@bFfFfA~@jAx@fCxAdE`CxBz@tA`@tATnJlAtATrA^jAh@bG|DjAt@h@Tf@PvAPbA@rAOvOkCnEu@l@QZO\O|@s@tAaBnA_Bf@g@ZSd@]h@Wp@Sh@If@Ct@AzBJtDXf@Hr@N|Aj@zDlBtK~FbAd@fA^dARlAJrCPtKp@`D\lCl@dAXtAl@|F|B~JfEnChAv@b@~@v@t@~@TZl@pAj@hBZlBCl@@r@P|G?ZLpEPbG@n@\vEj@hM`BnTFpAx@vLp@~If@vGNzAVdBj@lBpAfC~@jBtAtD`G|LjA|Bc@h@&path=color:0x0000ff|weight:3|enc:gkmwFp|tbMb@i@hAxB^v@xA`C~DhHb@r@pBvDxAxCz@nBn@tB^xAjAjIJlAEHwCl@[HFXD`CGh@o@v@*@^q@Zo@HwD_@c@GW?UCEVMp@WhBIx@Cl@BrAFhAHvAEh@CTQn@_@l@i@b@c@R[Fs@@YCw@Sg@S_EcCcC_B{@dCqD}B[Q_A_@}@WoBk@&path=color:0x228B22|weight:3|40.7105139,-74.0155469|40.710611491308946,-74.01606188413086|40.710009675958524,-74.01634083386841|40.71043257379994,-74.01814327832642|40.70942214380081,-74.0224762910866|40.70942214380081,-74.0224762910866|40.708643372269236,-74.02586804028931|40.708643372269236,-74.02595387097779|40.6998918576991,-74.02623282071533|40.69009790752417,-74.03217659589234|40.68944709570568,-74.04419289227905|40.6892494,-74.0445004&key=AIzaSyBZ2ijM7ygGfp_BPNY2ClcoSexWta8rXXQ&language=en"

The point here is the markers are separated by "&" operator and path parameter is pretty straight forward has lat/lng coordinates separated by a "|" operator. For the enc parameter you can visit this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility) to find the encoded polyline. Create your polyines and get the encoded values. Finally merge the parameter same as given in the example and you will get the static map image as you want.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Please note that in my question I wrote that it works well in some cases, but not in others. When it doesn't work it sometimes shows only the enc and sometimes show only the lat/lng paths.

Comment: But how is that possible.. I mean once the static image has been loaded it should show all the components it is made up of like markers, polylines etc. The problem could be with the underlying platform.